# Get VRAM Total using OpenHardwareMonitor NuGet package

Tags: c#, openhardwaremonitor

I am currently trying to get the value of a GPU's total VRAM using the Nuget package [OpenHardwareMonitor](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenHardwareMonitor).

I know that it is possible to get the value through the use of the package, however, I have been trying for quite a while, and have not found the specific code for completing the task.

I am not looking for the answer of getting the total VRAM using any other means, such as WMI. I am just looking for an answer using OpenHardwareMonitor.

If you have the solution to this problem, that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the NuGet package is built from an older version of the code. In the meantime additional sensors have been added that include details about total, free and used GPU memory (at least for NVidea GPU's). See [this diff](https://github.com/openhardwaremonitor/openhardwaremonitor/commit/d7a7ccd1bc913fb1276da82caeb5c57010cfc9fb#diff-dc9f343031627469cc06d90686650908).

*If* that package ever gets updated, you should be able to find the memory details in the list of sensors:

```
var computer = new Computer();
computer.GPUEnabled = true;
computer.Open();
var gpu = computer.Hardware.First(x => x.HardwareType == HardwareType.GpuNvidia);
var totalVideoRamInMB = gpu.Sensors.First(x => x.Name.Equals("GPU Memory Total")).Value / 1024;
computer.Close();
```

Until then, a workaround would be to extract the memory information from the `GetReport()` result, where the GPU memory information looks like this:

```
Memory Info

 Value[0]: 2097152
 Value[1]: 2029816
 Value[2]: 0
 Value[3]: 8221004
 Value[4]: 753168
```

Where `Value[0]` is the total GPU memory and `Value[4]` the amount of free GPU memory in kB. So with some regex magic, we can extract that information:

```
var pattern = @"Memory Info.*Value\[0\]:\s*(?<total>[0-9]+).*Value\[4\]:\s*(?<free>[0-9]+)";
var computer = new Computer();
computer.GPUEnabled = true;
computer.Open();
var gpu = computer.Hardware.First(x => x.HardwareType == HardwareType.GpuNvidia);
var report = gpu.GetReport();
var match = Regex.Match(report, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
var totalVideoRamInMB = float.Parse(match.Groups["total"].Value) / 1024;
var freeVideoRamInMB = float.Parse(match.Groups["free"].Value) / 1024;
computer.Close();
```

Note that OpenHardwareMonitor only implements GPU memory information for NVidea GPU's.

Comment: Great! Thanks for this! I had a question about the line of code declaring the var "gpu". Is there any reason for the "Hardware.First...." command? I can get it to run using a foreach loop, but I wasn't sure if there was a specific purpose for doing it the other way.

Comment: Just serves as an example, you could use a foreach if you expect more than one GPU.